# deleting elements of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have implemented a linked list that put their elements in front of the list everytime I call to a function, for example:

```
30-->40
|
first

//add 50

30-->40-->50
|
first
```

the code I implemented is the following:

```
public class Node {
    public int elem;
    Node next;
    public Node(int e){
        this.elem=e;
    }
}

public class List {
    Nodo list;
    Nodo first;
    public void addFront(int n){
        Nodo temp=new Nodo(n);
        if (list==null){
            first=temp;
        }
        else{
            list.next=temp;
        }
        list=temp;
    }

    public void print(){
        Nodo current;
        current=first;
        while (current!=null){
            System.out.println(current.elem);
            current=current.next;
        }
    }
    public Nodo deletefirst(){
        first=first.next;
        return list;
    }
public int size(){
        Nodo temp;
        temp=first;
        int c=0;
        while (temp!=null){
            c++;
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

the problem I got is in my main program, when I do something like this:

```
List list4=new List();
list4.addFront(10);
list4.addFront(20);
list4.addFront(40);
list4.addFront(60);
list4.addFront(80);
for (int i=0;i<list4.size();i++){
    List4.deletefirst();
    System.out.println("List");
    List4.print();
}
```

the list that is visualized is the following:

```
list
20
40
60
80
list
40
60
80
list
60
80
```

how can I change my code so that it prints the missed values of the list, I mean:

```
list
80
list
null
```

Any help?

Comment: I wonder why you though a `for` loop with `i < list4.size()` would be helpful here. You do realize that `i` increments whereas `list4.size()` _decrements_?

Comment: thanks @Tom, silly mistake of mine, I changed that

Comment: Not quite sure what you want when you say 'missed values'. But if you return the value you delete each time you can maintain a separate array of deleted items - i.e. have deleteFirst return the value it deletes.

Comment: Then this should fix the issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To add in front of the list:

```
public class List {
    Nodo first;

    public void addFront(int n){
        Nodo temp = new Nodo(n);
        temp.next = first;
        first = temp:
    }
```

Often `first` is named `head` as in "head of the list."

There is only one field needed to point to the first node.

Debugging your code, is best done on paper by mental execution.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to a while loop.

```
List list4=new List();
list4.addFront(10);
list4.addFront(20);
list4.addFront(40);
list4.addFront(60);
list4.addFront(80);
while (list4.size() > 0){
    list4.deletefirst();
    System.out.println("List");
    List4.print();
}
```

The for loop you were using increased i while decreasing the size of the list which is ripe for off-by-one errors or in your case off-by-two errors.

<strike>Important to note that I used .isEmpty() vs. < 0. This wouldn't matter in this code snippet but it is best practice.</strike>
@azurefrog raises the point that this is a custom implementation of List without a isEmpty()

Comment: Add a ```System.out.println("List" + "\n" + "null")``` after the while loop and you are done.

Comment: The OP is using their own custom linked list implementation that doesn't have an `isEmpty()` method to use the way you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not properly an answer, but i don't have enough points to comment. You maybe interested in a iterator. You may need to change the Nodo list into a java.util.List , but then you can play with your list really easily declaring a `Iterator<Nodo> it = list4.list.iterator()` . The loop would become:

```
while(it.hasNext()){                 
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
System.out.println(it.next());          //outside the loop it.next() point to null
```